# Can we have two LB infront of Control Plane?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, wso2-api-manager, mod-proxy, internal-load-balancer

Can we have two Proxies/LBs infront of Control Plane
One is for Publisher , accessible to Internal staff only
The other is for DevPortal which can be accessible by Both Internal Staff and external users ?

Installed Gateway runtime in HA
Installed Gateway Control Plane in HA